# Google fonts enqueue only imports last font family

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to import three google fonts by adding the following to my `functions.php` file:

```
function get_google_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'get-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap', false ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_google_fonts' );
```

However, WordPress seems to be enqueueing only the last font (here, `Roboto`) when I view my site.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="get-google-fonts-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap&amp;ver=5.5" type="text/css" media="all">
```

The site is new and WordPress is just installed. There are no plugins installed yet. What is the reason for this?

### EDIT:

I tried splitting up the fonts into separate enqueues as follows and the fonts are all working now:

```
function get_google_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'get-font-1', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'get-font-2', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Tamma+2&display=swap', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'get-font-3', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_google_fonts' );
```

But I don't understand why the single request approach didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

From the [`wp_enqueue_style()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/):

> **$ver** 
> *(string|bool|null) (Optional)* String specifying stylesheet version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as
> a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false,
> a version number is automatically added equal to current installed
> WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added.
>
> *Default value: false*

So when the version number is not *exactly* a `null` (i.e. `$ver !== null`), WordPress uses [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) to add the version number and because the function supports only one instance of the same query string (except for arrays like `family[]` and `foo_bar[]`), the previous `family` queries in the stylesheet URL are removed by `add_query_arg()`.

Therefore, you can either enqueue the font families one per `wp_enqueue_style()` call (like you've tried), or set the `$ver` to `null` (and manually add the version number or cache buster query):

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'get-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap', array(), null );
```